# Python list - finding the index of the element in the triplet that lies between other two elements

Tags: python, list

This is my code:

```
lst = []
 
for i in range(0, 3):
    ele = int(input("Enter elements of the list: "))
 
    lst.append(ele) 

for x in lst:
    if ((x > lst[0] or x > lst[1] or x > lst[2]) and (x < lst [0] or x < lst[1] or x < lst[2])): 
        print(x)
```

It works fine, printing the element that lies between other two elements (is greater than the less and less than the greater), but I need the index of that element. I tried

```
lst = []
 
for i in range(0, 3):
    ele = int(input("Enter elements of the list: "))
 
    lst.append(ele) 

for x in lst:
    if ((x > lst[0] or x > lst[1] or x > lst[2]) and (x < lst [0] or x < lst[1] or x < lst[2])): 
        print lst.index(x)
```

But I got error that there is no index of int value.

If someone knows how I can solve this, I would appreciate that. Also if there is a more elegant solution, be free to post it.

Comment: [mre] .........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were you, I'd try:

```
lst = []
 
for i in range(0, 3):
    ele = int(input("Enter elements of the list: "))
 
    lst.append(ele) 

for i, x in enumerate(lst):  # changed to enumerate
    if ((x > lst[0] or x > lst[1] or x > lst[2]) and (x < lst [0] or x < lst[1] or x < lst[2])): 
    print(i, x)
```

Now the code prints the index of the element and its value.

Answer (score 1):

A simple and concise solution is to combine `enumerate` and `sorted` using the second element of `enumerate`'s output to sort:

```
lst = [0,2,1]
sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])[1][0]
#                                          ↑position that is searched
```

output: `1`

Advantage, this works even if there are repeated values. For example `[0,0,0]` -> `1`

From this, it is easy to generalize to any length. For instance to take the middle element of 5 values:

```
lst = [0,2,4,1,3]
sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x: x[1])[3][0]
```

output: `4`

@don't talk just code pointed to the alternative `lst.index(sorted(lst)[1])` (where `1` is the position that is wanted, here the middle element for a list of 3)

Comment: Simple and concise? `lst.index(sorted(lst)[1])`

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode this doesn't do exactly the same, index would always take the first item if values are repeated, but I guess OP wasn't clear on that point ;)

Comment: Right... though their title, code and text all rather make it sound like they won't have duplicates.

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode that's probably right ;) I added your proposal, feel free to remove it if you want

Comment: How about `sorted(zip(lst, range(3)))[1][1]`? I think that's equivalent to yours.

Comment: Sure, this is equivalent. This reminds me that I've wished many time there would be an enumerate variant that puts the indexer after the value :)

Comment: Yes, `index = dict(erateenum(lst))` would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the min and max functions.

You've got your code set up to do a complicated comparison for each element, when there's a much more straight-forward way to do it, using Python's built-in min() and max() functions.

Also, you should use try and except for sanitizing user input.

```
lst = []
 
for i in range(0, 3):
    lst.append("placeholder")
    while isinstance(lst[i], int) is False:
      try:
        ele = int(input("Enter elements of the list: "))
      except:
        print("Type an integer")
      else:
        lst[i] = ele 

minimum = min(lst)
maximum = max(lst)

for x in enumerate(lst):
  if minimum < x[1] < maximum: 
    print(x)
```

Comment: Maybe `if min(lst) < x[1] < max(lst):`?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode That'd be less computationally efficient because you'd be calling min() and max() with every iteration across the list, rather than just once. Overall computational efficiency would be big O (n^2) rather than big O (n).

Comment: Meh, n=3, so it's all O(1). But ok, how about just `if minimum < x[1] < maximum:` then?

Comment: @don'ttalkjustcode Is constructing a statement like that with multiple < operators chained together legal in Python? You could certainly use < and/or > operators instead of != operators, though, sure.

Comment: Yes, [they're chained](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). Now I'm curious: Where do you know the term "chained operators" from? I only know it because of Python :-)